# Write a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times

Tags: mysql, select

I'm practicing SQL language and got a question like:

Write a SQL query to find all numbers that appear at least three times consecutively.

```
+----+-----+
| Id | Num |
+----+-----+
| 1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |
| 3  |  1  |
| 4  |  2  |
| 5  |  1  |
| 6  |  2  |
| 7  |  2  |
+----+-----+
```

For example, given the above Logs table, 1 is the only number that appears consecutively for at least three times.

I got a solution online and test it. But I really do not understand it. The big
picture of the solution is clear. `sq` table counts the occurrences. But I did not understand the part of computing the `sq`. I've done a lot of research on the MYSQL. `@counter := IF(@prev = Num, @counter + 1, 1)` means if prev = Num, making counter = counter + 1, otherwise counter = 1. `(SELECT @counter:=1, @prev:=NULL) vars` means create a table `vars` which includes two columns `counter` and `pre`.

Can anyone help me explain the logic of the `sq` part? Or is there any tutorial for this kind of expressions in the `SELECT`? I'm totally new to SQL and I know this question may be pretty simple. Thanks for your help!

```
SELECT  DISTINCT(Num) AS ConsecutiveNums
FROM (
    SELECT
    Num,
    @counter := IF(@prev = Num, @counter + 1, 1) AS how_many_cnt_in_a_row,
    @prev := Num
    FROM Logs y, (SELECT @counter:=1, @prev:=NULL) vars
) sq
WHERE how_many_cnt_in_a_row >= 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the line below is simply initializing variables `@counter` and `@prev`. For more information about it check [User Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

```
(SELECT @counter:=1, @prev:=NULL)
```

So, `sq` is not an actual table, but it works as an alias so you can reference these in-memory variables.`@counter` variable counts how many numbers are in consecutive order, when the previous number `@prev` is different from the actual one `Num`, `@counter` is reset to 1 and the counting process starts again.

In order to be clearer, here is what would be the values for `sq`:

`+-----+-----------------------+
| Num | how_many_cnt_in_a_row |
+-----+-----------------------+
| 1   |  1  |
| 1   |  2  |
| 1   |  3  |
| 2   |  1  |
| 1   |  1  |
| 2   |  1  |
| 2   |  2  |
+-----+-----+`

Comment: THanks. THis is exactly what I want. Actually, I also just figured it out by myself. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3616/2

Answer (score 11):

Let's go through each record and see how this query works. It's well written.

**SELECT...FROM**

What does `SELECT...FROM Logs y, (...) vars` mean?

If you had a table like this: `create table test(field1 int)` that contains 3 rows like so:

```
field1
-------
1
2
3
```

Doing `select * from test, (select @counter:=1, @prev:=NULL) vars` will result in

```
field1  @counter:=1  @prev=NULL
------- ------------ -----------
1       1            NULL
2       1            NULL
3       1            NULL
```

`@counter` and `@prev` are session variables. They are initialized to 1 and NULL respectively. All rows are combined with these variables to give you what you see above.

**Row by row analysis of the subquery**

Focus on just this subquery.

```
SELECT
Num,
@counter := IF(@prev = Num, @counter + 1, 1) AS how_many_cnt_in_a_row,
@prev := Num
FROM Logs y, (SELECT @counter:=1, @prev:=NULL) vars
```

The query selects the first row of ID=1, Num=1, and chooses Num as it's first column.

For the 2nd column, it does some math. It checks if `@prev = Num`. Well, @prev is NULL because that's how it was initialized. So, `@prev = Num` results in false. `IF` is generally written as `IF(condition, what-to-do-if-condition-is-true, what-to-do-if-condition-is-false)`.

```
IF(@prev = Num, @counter + 1, 1)
   -----------  ------------  --
   condition    do this       do this if condition
                if true       is false
```

Since @prev is NULL and not equal to Num, 1 is returned.

For the 3rd column, the query just resets @prev to Num. That's really all. Now let's see how SELECT goes line by line and does its magic.

```
Num  @prev was  @counter was  @counter calculation      @prev reset to Num
---  ---------  ------------  -----------------------   ------------------
1    NULL       1             is @prev = 1? No. So 1      1
1    1          1             is @prev = 1? Yes! So 2     1
1    1          2             is @prev = 1? Yes! So 3     1
2    1          3             is @prev = 2? No. So 1      2
1    2          1             is @prev = 1? No. So 1      1
2    1          1             is @prev = 2? No. So 1      2
2    2          1             is @prev = 2? Yes! So 2     2
```

The 2nd and 3rd column above are for understanding purposes only.

Now that the subquery has done its job, `SELECT DISTINCT...` comes and asks: From the result above, give me only the row that has @counter of 3 or higher. The result is going to be

```
Num   @counter  @prev
----  --------  -----
1     3         1
```

If your dataset had five `1`s one after the other, 3rd, 4th and 5th `1` will be retrieved. Therefore, DISTINCT(Num) is used to select only a single `1`. It's just smart thinking. It may be possible to change the `WHERE` clause to read `WHERE ... = 3` insted of `>= 3`.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! It's hard for me to choose which one as the correct answer since @djeison also gives the correct idea and earlier (but not as detail as your). I always do not figure out the rule at stackoverflow for the correct answer. The first almost correct one get the mark or the absolute correct and more detailed one.

Comment: You chose the right answer as the correct answer. djeison answered 14 minutes ahead of me and is a meaningful, correct answer. I added my detailed note for reference. So keep djeison's post as the answer - that's my recommendation.

Comment: This is simply amazing.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT 
    distinct A.num as ConsecutiveNums 
FROM
    LOGS A
INNER JOIN Logs B
    on A.id=b.id+1
INNER join Logs C
    on b.id=c.id+1
WHERE a.num=b.num AND a.num=c.num
;
```

Comment: Please format the SQL with the code tags. Also you should explain what your query exactly does.

Comment: Its also good to give some idea of your DDL Scripts and also Data  use something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ to provide a minimal reproducible example as per rules. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
select ConsecutiveNums from(    
        select 
        case 
        when lag(Num) over (order by Id) = Num and Num=lead(Num) over (order by 
        Id)  then Num 
        end as ConsecutiveNums
        from Logs
        )  
where ConsecutiveNums is not null
```

Comment: Code only answers are more helpful if you add an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version of the answer...

```
select distinct num 
  from ( 
          select num
                ,lag(num,1) over() as lag1
                ,lag(num,2) over() as lag2
             from
                 logs
       ) as a
   where  num = lag1 = lag2
     and  lag1 = lag2
```

Comment: when come negative values it give null

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Num
FROM (
  SELECT Num,
         LAG(Num) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS prev_num,
         LEAD(Num) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS next_num
  FROM your_table
) AS subquery
WHERE Num = prev_num AND Num = next_num;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct num from ( select num,
                            lag(num,1) over(order by ID) lag1,
                            lead(num,1) over(order by ID) lead1
                            from Table
                            ) as a
    where num=lag1 and num=lead1
    and lag1=lead1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to check if next ids have the same value as current id

```
SELECT DISTINCT Num as ConsecutiveNums
FROM Logs
WHERE (Id + 1, Num) IN (SELECT * FROM Logs) AND (Id + 2, Num) IN (SELECT * FROM Logs)
```