# Query that checks for a value A to appear at least B number of times in C columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, google-bigquery

I'm trying to select rows from a table where some value `a` is within `c` columns at least `b` times.

Here is a simplified example of the data I'm working with. I'm trying to find rows that have an `h` in at least 2 of the greetings.

| greeting1 | greeting2 | greeting3 | farewell1 | farewell2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***h***i | ***h***ello | ***h***ey there | goodbye | peace |
| ***h***i | sup | yo | Au revoir | see ya |
| yo | ***h***ola | ayyyy | hang tight | reverse-hi |
| ***h***ola | sup | ***h***ello | see ya | peace |
| ***h***ello | yo | ***h***ola | hang tight | ciao |
| ayyy | yo | ***h***ola | hang tight | ciao |

And below are the rows I'd like to grab:

| greeting1 | greeting2 | greeting3 | farewell1 | farewell2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ***h***i | ***h***ello | ***h***ey there | goodbye | peace |
| ***h***ola | sup | ***h***ello | see ya | peace |
| ***h***ello | yo | ***h***ola | hang tight | ciao |

(I italicized and bolded for easier ability to see)

I'm just learning SQL, so this might be basic. I was having some difficulties. I know getting the rows and checking all greeting1 would look something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  GreetingsAndFarewell
WHERE
  greetings1 LIKE '%h%'
  AND greetings2 LIKE '%h%'
  AND greetings3 LIKE '%h%'
```

But what if I only care if at least 2 greetings have an `h` in them?

Here are some of the similar questions I've seen, but I don't think either of them really address this:

[5760335](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760335/sql-select-rows-with-a-column-value-that-occurs-at-least-n-times)
[31577623](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577623/write-a-sql-query-to-find-all-numbers-that-appear-at-least-three-times)

Comment: If you add your sample data as DDL+DML you make it *much* easier for people to assist.

Comment: And SQL Server <> Google Big Query - please only tag the relevant product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use try summing `CASE` expressions which check for the letter `h` in each of the 3 greetings:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM GreetingsAndFarewell
WHERE CASE WHEN greetings1 LIKE '%h%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN greetings2 LIKE '%h%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN greetings3 LIKE '%h%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >= 2;
```

On BigQuery you might be able to directly sum boolean expressions and simplify to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM GreetingsAndFarewell
WHERE greetings1 LIKE '%h%' + greetings2 LIKE '%h%' + greetings3 LIKE '%h%' >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not having luck on the second portion of your answer, but the first works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select *
from GreetingsAndFarewell
where (
  select count(1)
  from unnest([greeting1, greeting2, greeting3]) greeting
  where greeting like '%h%'
) >= 2
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Formatted text is the preferred method of displaying data. It works better for everyone.